# Using long data inside signal handler.

Tags: c++, c, linux, signals

How can I set a variable of type `long` (on 64 bit machine = 8 bytes) inside a signal handler? I've read that you can only use variables of type `sig_atomic_t`, which is actually implemented as `volatile int` inside a signal handler and it is unsafe to modify data types bigger than an `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* use a `long` inside a signal handler, you can use anything, in fact. The only thing you should take care of is proper synchronization in order to avoid race conditions.

`sig_atomic_t` should be used for variables shared between the signal handler and the rest of the code. Any variable "private" to the signal handler can be of *any* type, *any* size.

Sample code :

```
#include <signal.h>

static volatile long badShared; // NOT OK: shared not sig_atomic_t
static volatile sig_atomic_t goodShared; // OK: shared sig_atomic_t

void handler(int signum)
{
    int  localInt  = 17;
    long localLong = 23; // OK: not shared

    if (badShared == 0) // NOT OK: shared not sig_atomic_t
        ++badShared;

    if (goodShared == 0) // OK: shared sig_atomic_t
        ++goodShared;
}

int main()
{
    signal(SOMESIGNAL, handler);
    badShared++; // NOT OK: shared not sig_atomic_t
    goodShared++; // OK: shared sig_atomic_t

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to use a shared variable other than `sig_atomic_t` use atomics (`atomic_long_read`, `atomic_long_set`).

Comment: You can't use a lock to synchronize with a signal handler - it would just deadlock because the signal handler doesn't run in parallel like a thread.