# Accessing long integers in signal handlers

Tags: c, signals

I understand that accessing static variables in signal handlers is undefined behaviour, unless the variable is declared as `volatile sig_atomic_t`. I am, however, writing a program for a 64-bit machine, where sig_atomic_t happens to be 32-bit. Is there an `long` equivalent of `sig_atomic_t` which I can use?

I know that `sig_atomic_t` is merely a typedef of `int`, so maybe a `volatile long` will do; I'm just not comfortable with doing anything that is specifically undefined behaviour.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer appears to be "no", there is no `long` analog which is covered by the standard.  The answer for [Linux: Why is sig_atomic_t typedef'ed to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606725/linux-why-is-sig-atomic-t-typedefed-to-int) goes into a lot of detail, and the quoted standards pointedly omit any types which could be larger than an integer.

As noted in [Using long data inside signal handler.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882753/using-long-data-inside-signal-handler), a signal handler can of course *access* data of any type, but cannot rely upon sharing data of other types.

Comment: I suppose I've misunderstood the reason why some functions aren't safe in signal handler context, why sig_atomic_t is a typedef of int, etc. I gave it some thought and it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

The new C11 standard specified an optional concurrency model and a couple of types, which are safe for use in signal handlers.

Regarding signal handlers, it now says (emphasis mine):

> the behavior is undefined if the signal handler refers to any object with static or thread storage duration that is not a ***lock-free atomic object*** other than by assigning a value to an object declared as ***volatile sig_atomic_t***

A Lock-free type is one which the underlying architecture directly supports doing atomic operations on (locks need not be used).

So, `#if __STDC_NO_ATOMICS__!=1` and `<stdatomic.h>` `#define`s `ATOMIC_LONG_LOCK_FREE`, you are guaranteed well-defined behaviour using `atomic_long` from `<stdatomic.h>` in place of `volatile sig_atomic_t`. This is e.g. the case with GCC 4.9+ on AMD64.